# Provisioning profile after ios update

Tags: ios, xcode

Just read the iOS 8.1 release notes and it states this

Provisioning Profiles
Known Issue
If you have upgraded to the 8.1 Beta from iOS 8 betas you may see your apps crashing due to provisioning profile issues.

Workaround:

Connect the device via USB to your Mac
Launch Xcode
Choose Window -> Devices
Right click on the device in left column, choose "Show Provisioning Profiles"
Click on the provisioning profile in question
Press the "-" button
Continue to removing all affected profiles.
Re-install the app
Speech Synthesis

My app keeps crashing on iOS 8 and I made the Provisioning profile during iOS 7. Do I need to create an new one for me to test on iOS 8?

Sorry I am new to xcode

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Zil no error just crashes after 5 seconds. It worked perfectly on iOS 7

Comment: How can you be sure its provisioning profile related? Does it crash BEFORE your very first viewDidLoad?

Comment: if prov profile is messed up I think you wont be able to install and/or run your app at all.